# Updating a feature with develop while I'm developing it. Is it Gitflow?

Tags: merge, branch, conflict, git-flow

When I create a feature, I create a branch from develop. Then when the functionality is finished, I merge it to develop but there are many conflicts because develop has been updated with other functionalities.

What my team has recommended to me is to constantly update develop and immediately merged to the feature I'm developing.

That way I wouldn't have as many conflicts when I merge the feature when it's done.

My questions are:

1. This way of working is still Gitflow? or is it a variant of it?
2. If this way of working is not gitflow, does it have any other name?
3. What happens if there is a bug in develop and my feature inherits
   it?

Best regards.

[image: Gitflow as I know it]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you *merge the branches* (with `git merge <branch-name>` or with `git flow feature start <branch-name>` and then for merging with `git flow feature finish <branch-name>`). If you do it like the *second approach*, it's **git-flow**, otherwise it's just **"normal"** git.

I would *first create* a *git flow branch* from the *develop branch* (`git flow feature start <branch-name>`) and then make the changes there.  Everytime you want to *push* changes, you do `git push` (the **first time** it has to be `git-flow feature publish <branch-name>`!!!) Then all changes are *visible* on the git server under the branch name *feature/*.

If you want to merge the *feature branch* and the *develop branch*, just do `git flow feature publish <branch-name>`.

### How to resolve merge conflicts

There are lots of tools that can help you do this. As you may have already guessed, I’m most comfortable with using a text editor. It just seems to be clearer and I’m less fearful of doing something accidentally by clicking on a UI button. Find the file and then make the changes.
Generic steps for any file:

- Find <<<<<HEAD. Look for ======
- Everything between HEAD and === is what you have in your code.
- Everything between === and >>>>develop is what the develop branch has.
- Figure out what you want to keep and then delete <<<<HEAD, ==== and >>>> develop.

If it is a bug in the *feature branch* where merged in *develop branch*, so the bug is in the *develop branch* too, except the bug gives a merge conflict (because there is different code at this point) that you have to edit manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I rephrase my question:

I create feature1 from develop.

I work on feature1 (don't finish).

I pull on develop and it brings me changes (new features from other programmers)

In GitFlow:
it is correct to merge:
this new develop with feature1 (which is not finished yet)?

Comment: The `release branch` must be used in git flow for your explaining application. There you can then make various release versions of this branch. [git-flow cheatsheet](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/). Nice *git-flow workflow* explaining [here](https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)